# How do I set a join model's attribute on the fly when creating a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a has_many :through relationship between users and projects via an ownership join model. I want to be able to set an attribute of the ownership model while creating a relationship between a user and a new project. Here is what I have so far:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    if @project.save
      current_user.projects << @project
      flash[:success] = "Project created!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      flash[:error] = "Project not created."
    end
  end
```

Basically, I don't know how to set the value "owner_type" in the ownership model when creating a new project for a given user since I don't directly mention the ownership join model in the project creation controller. How do I do that?

Here is my ownership (join) model:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_type

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  validates :project_id, :presence => true

  validates :owner_type, :presence => true

end
```

and my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :admin, :projects

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :projects, :through => :ownerships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
```

and my Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :description

      has_many :ownerships
      has_many :users, :through => :ownerships
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that you build (not create) the association before you hit `@project.save` when you hit save the project is persisted first and if it was persisted successfully, the ownership will be created too.

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])
  @project.ownerships.build(:user => current_user, :owner_type => 'chief')

  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to @project
  else
    flash[:error] = "Project not created."
  end
end
```

Comment: Phew, I noticed your answer was gone and freaked out a bit:). 

Ok, I will try this. Do I need to add an attr_accessible to anything to get this to work? Like, :user to the ownership model?

Comment: **Edit: maybe you can ignore the following, just try it as it is - because you are not assigning the `user_id` directly**

Either remove `attr_accessible :owner_type` or add `user_id` and `project_id` too. Because if you set `attr_accessible` on one attribute, all other attributes won't be accessible through mass assignment unless you declare them accessible explicitly. Quote: _If any attributes are protected by either attr_protected or attr_accessible then only settable attributes will be assigned._

Comment: This didn't work. No error was thrown but it redirected to /projects, but it wasn't actually the /projects page it was a project#create page but it looked funky. The project didn't save either, nor did the ownership model. When I remove @project.ownerships.build(:user => current_user, :owner_type => 'designer'), it creates the project properly again but doesn't create the ownership (obviously). Also, I removed ALL attr_accessible just to try to get this to work.

Comment: Got it to work! Here's what I did: I changed the build to create and moved it to after the project.save. Edited your answer to show it.

Comment: that's what I did in my previous answer :)

Comment: yes, the main problem was that I set an attr_accessible for :owner_type but didn't set it for :user and :project, which was necessary to create the join model the way mentioned above. I didnt know that. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This didn't actually work for me.

In my user model I allow for nested attributes with this line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
```

Then, in my projects#create controller action, I nested an attribute while creating the association between the user and the new project as so:

```
current_user.ownerships.create(:owner_type => 'designer', :project => @project)
```

To be honest I'm not sure exactly why this works but it does. Would be awesome for someone else to explain it.